# White gaps/blank space with stacked area graph (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have followed the guidance [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/136-stacked-area-chart.html) to generate a stacked area graph for four groups within a categorical variable. The code works without errors but for some reason the graph contains white gaps, as you can see below. And I have checked those specific periods such as Oct and Nov and the data are complete for both months, and thus it should not be displaying white gaps. I am also open to other graph recommendations for the same data?
#install packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(ggthemes)
library(writexl)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(textclean)
library(lubridate)
```

Here is a data example:

```
dput(stackedgraph[1:20,c(1,2,4)])
```

output

```
structure(list(month_year = structure(c(2011.91666666667, 2011.91666666667, 
2011.91666666667, 2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012.08333333333, 
2012.08333333333, 2012.08333333333, 2012.08333333333, 2012.16666666667, 
2012.16666666667, 2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 2012.25, 2012.25, 
2012.25, 2012.33333333333), class = "yearmon"), directed_to_whom = c("MoE", 
"MoL", "Non-critical", "Private employers", "MoE", "MoL", "Non-critical", 
"Private employers", "MoE", "MoL", "Non-critical", "Private employers", 
"MoE", "Non-critical", "Private employers", "MoE", "MoL", "Non-critical", 
"Private employers", "MoE"), directed_to_whom_percentage = c(0.0923076923076923, 
0.107692307692308, 0.430769230769231, 0.369230769230769, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.45, 0.4, 0.0606060606060606, 0.121212121212121, 
0.287878787878788, 0.53030303030303, 0.184210526315789, 0.342105263157895, 
0.473684210526316, 0.131578947368421, 0.105263157894737, 0.210526315789474, 
0.552631578947368, 0.108108108108108)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    month_year = structure(c(2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012.08333333333, 
    2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 2012.33333333333), class = "yearmon"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:15, 16:19, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here is the code to create the graph:

```
ggplot(stackedgraph, aes(x = as.Date(month_year),y = directed_to_whom_percentage)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=directed_to_whom,group = directed_to_whom), position='stack') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("MoL" = "light green",
                              "MoE" = "red",
                               "Private employers" = "light blue",
                              "Non-critical" = "black")) +
          scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme_economist_white() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

output:
[image]

I really appreciate the advice from Andy, I ran the code with a small change:

```
stackedgraph <- stackedgraph %>%
  ungroup() %>% # I used ungroup to avoid this [error][3] which I was receiving.
  complete(month_year, directed_to_whom, fill = list(directed_to_whom_percentage = 0))
```

Then the graph:

```
ggplot(stackedgraph, aes(x = as.Date(month_year), y = directed_to_whom_percentage)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = directed_to_whom, group = directed_to_whom),
            position = 'stack') +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "MoL" = "light green",
      "MoE" = "red",
      "Private employers" = "light blue",
      "Non-critical" = "black"
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing a reproducible small sample of data, however in this case I don't think your sample is enough to demonstrate the problem. Your plot code run on those 10 rows of sample data returns exactly what I would expect. Can you find a sample of data that illustrates the problem? Perhaps the subset of data up through Jan-12 would show how the red and black group areas don't extend back to Oct-11.

Comment: It would also be nice if you would only include `library()` calls for **relevant** packages. At a glance, `stringr`, `writexl`, `hrbrthemes`, `textclean` and `viridis` are all not needed here. And there's not really any point in including `ggthemes` and the `theme_economist_white()` call unless that has something to do with the issue - does the plot look correct for the default theme but break when you use `theme_economist_white()`? If not, take it out!

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks, I have added a longer data sample, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would need a row with a `0` for every category in months when it has a value of zero - the area chart is extrapolating for missing months thereby adding over 100% in some cases. You can do a quick fix with a `pivot_wider`/`pivot_longer` combo to fill in missing 0s:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

# Creating sample data to test
stackedgraph <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~month_year,   ~directed_to_whom, ~directed_to_whom_percentage,
                   "Dec 2011",               "MoE",           0.0923076923076923,
                   "Dec 2011",               "MoL",            0.107692307692308,
                   "Dec 2011",      "Non-critical",            0.430769230769231,
                   "Dec 2011", "Private employers",            0.369230769230769,
                   "Jan 2012",               "MoE",           0.0666666666666667,
                   "Jan 2012",               "MoL",           0.0833333333333333,
                   "Jan 2012",      "Non-critical",                         0.45,
                   "Jan 2012", "Private employers",                          0.4,
                   "Feb 2012",               "MoE",           0.0606060606060606,
                   "Feb 2012",               "MoL",            0.121212121212121,
                   "Feb 2012",      "Non-critical",            0.287878787878788,
                   "Feb 2012", "Private employers",             0.53030303030303,
                   "Mar 2012",               "MoE",            0.184210526315789,
                   "Mar 2012",      "Non-critical",            0.342105263157895,
                   "Mar 2012", "Private employers",            0.473684210526316,
                   "Apr 2012",               "MoE",            0.131578947368421,
                   "Apr 2012",               "MoL",            0.105263157894737,
                   "Apr 2012",      "Non-critical",            0.210526315789474,
                   "Apr 2012", "Private employers",            0.552631578947368
                  ) |> 
  mutate(month_year = as.yearmon(month_year))

# Run this code on your data

stackedgraph |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = directed_to_whom,
              values_from = directed_to_whom_percentage,
              values_fill = 0) |>
  pivot_longer(-month_year, 
               names_to = "directed_to_whom",
               values_to = "directed_to_whom_percentage") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(month_year), y = directed_to_whom_percentage)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = directed_to_whom, group = directed_to_whom),
            position = 'stack') +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "MoL" = "light green",
      "MoE" = "red",
      "Private employers" = "light blue",
      "Non-critical" = "black"
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

[image]

### Edit - a slightly tidier solution

The `tidyr::complete` function can do the steps for you in a bit more of a natural/explicit way. This will create every `month_year`*`directed_to_whom` combo in the dataframe and fill missing values with 0s:

```r
stackedgraph <- stackedgraph %>%
  complete(month_year,
           directed_to_whom,
           fill = list(directed_to_whom_percentage = 0))
```

This does the same as the two pivots but is the nicer, proper way of doing it. This will then give the tidied, expanded dataframe which should pass to your `ggplot` code giving the right results.

Comment: Thanks Andy, is it possible to still the Jan 2012 data for the variable of interest "directed_to_whom" even if other variables are missing?
I have updated my post.

Comment: Hi @nesta1992 - yes it will be possible with your data, I've updated the answer to include all full year/month periods your example data includes. The January 2012 incompleteness in my previous answer was only because your pasted rows didn't have all the data for that month. If you run this on your dataset (with unnecessary lines removed) then it should work!

Comment: Thanks, I am still struggling to identify which lines are unnecessary and should be removed. See my updated post.

Comment: Have edited as above - all the code after creating a new `stackedgraph` dataframe should now run on yours and do the same job. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've also changed the code back more to what you had before (you used `zoo` `yearmonth` classes, I'd switched to `lubridate` for simplicity - have switched back now). Can you run the code above on your dataframe to see if it works or if it still produces grey spikes?

Comment: Thanks, your code worked well but I just had to do a slight modification to it. See the updated post.